# How can make transition stay in own zIndex until ending the transition in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have code like this in below:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var show: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            Button("show") { show.toggle() }.foregroundColor(.black)
                //.zIndex(1)
            
            if (show) {
                
                Circle()
                    .fill(.blue)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .transition(AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .offset(x: 0, y: 300), removal: .offset(x: 0, y: 300)))
                    .onTapGesture { show.toggle() }
                    //.zIndex(2)
                
            }
            
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        .padding()
        .animation(.linear(duration: 1.5), value: show)
        
    }
}
```

The issue with this code is that in insertion view stays in correct zIndex(in Top layer) but in removal goes to wrong zIndex(in Bottom layer), I can correct this issue with using direct zIndex but the goal of this question is to find a way **without using zIndex modifier**, I thing it is possible but not sure how, maybe it has something to do with transition.

Comment: @vacawama: I do not know if my feedback is really important for you, but between using my approach it mens having zIndex or using your approach having an unneeded Stack, I would use zIndex, your answer does not solve the issue it is just another approach like main for handling the issue. In your approach it would be a stack left over after show value became false, with my approach would be no left over.

Comment: Extra views in SwiftUI are essentially free.  Adding a single HStack is much easier to manage than adding a .zIndex to every view.  Every modifier in SwiftUI creates a new view.  Your question specified **the goal of this question is to find a way without using zIndex modifier** and my answer achieves that.  Of course I want feedback on an answer, even if its just a comment.  Please be in the habit of leaving at least a comment when someone has taken the time to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior seems like a bug.

I think this is a side effect of the fact that as soon as you remove the `Circle()` `View`, it is immediately gone, and the animation happens after the fact.  So upon removal, there is instantly just one item in the `ZStack` and it is on top.

A workaround is to not completely remove a view from the `ZStack`.  This can be accomplished by wrapping the `if show { }` with an `HStack`, `VStack`, or `ZStack`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var show: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            Button("show") { show.toggle() }.foregroundColor(.black)
                //.zIndex(1)

            HStack {   // Note: VStack and ZStack also work

                if (show) {
                    
                    Circle()
                        .fill(.blue)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .transition(AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .offset(x: 0, y: 300), removal: .offset(x: 0, y: 300)))
                        .onTapGesture { show.toggle() }
                    //.zIndex(2)
                }
            }
            
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        .padding()
        .animation(.linear(duration: 1.5), value: show)
    }
}
```

In this case, while the `Circle()` `View` is immediately removed, the `HStack` to which it belongs remains, and it remains in the same position in the `ZStack` thus fixing the animation.

That said, I'm not sure why adding explicit `.zIndex()` modifiers helps.

**Note:** Wrapping `if show() { }` in a `Group` does not help because `Group` is not a `View`.